# Inheritance not working in python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, multiple-inheritance

```
class One(object):
    def __init__(self, i = 0):
        print('one', i)

class Two(One):
    def __init__(self, i = 0):
        super().__init__(i)
        print('two', i)

class First(object):
    def __init__(self, i = 0):
        print('first', i)

class Second(First):
    def __init__(self, i = 0):
        super().__init__(i)
        print('second', i)

class Third(Second, Two):
    def __init__(self, i = 0):
        super().__init__(i)
        print('third', i)

class Fourth(Two, Second):
    def __init__(self, i = 0):
        super().__init__(i)
        print('fourth', i)
```

Output:
Third(3):
first 3
second 3
third 3

Fourth(4):
one 4
two 4
fourth 4

Why Inheritance not working, How can I fix it.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please describe your actual problem. I assure you inheritance works.

Comment: The formatting of your code is atrocious, using `<br>` and `&nbsp;` is not the way to format it. Just indent it by four spaces.

Comment: Please fix your code formatting! There are tools built into the post editor to do this.

Comment: As Carcigenicate suggests - describe what's the behavior you expect, i.e. what "inheritance not working" means according to you. It definitely works, the problem is that you expect something different, but you didn't describe what.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the formatting and fixed topic. But I am still getting error when I pass parameter in Base class.

Comment: Your quation still lacks a proper description of what you expect the output to be.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `super().__init__()` in the base classes `One` and `First` to allow the neighbouring classes to initialize.

```
class One(object):
    def __init__(self, i = 0):
        super().__init__()
        print('one', i)

....

class First(object):
    def __init__(self, i = 0):
        super().__init__()
        print('first', i)
....

>>> Fourth()
first 0
second 0
one 0
two 0
fourth 0
```

Comment: Output of Fourth(4) is not good, first and second still show 0, why ?

Comment: If I pass parameters in base class I receive error : TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters

Comment: without knowing your actual use case there is absolutely no way I can help you.  I'd recommend you try passing the name of the current class as the `i` value to see the chain of init calls leads but I'm not sure how you plan on using a setup like this in actual code.

Comment: maybe step through it in [pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)